# Quadratic character on Idele group becomes trivial for infinitely many places?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a number field and $\chi$ be a quadratic character of $\mathbb{A}^{\times}/F^{\times}$.

Then in some paper, it is written that $\chi_v$ is trivial for infinitely many places $v$ of $F$.

Why does it hold?

Comment: $\chi$ is given by a quadratic extension $K/F$, no? You can just consider the places where $K/F$ splits totally.

Comment: Don't you need continuous? If $\chi$ is continuous then $\ker(\chi)$ contains an open subgroup of $\Bbb{C}^{*j}\Bbb{R}^{*l}\widehat{O_F}^\times$ so it factors through $\Bbb{C}^{*j}\Bbb{R}^{*l}\prod_{N(\mathfrak{p})\le n} O_\mathfrak{p}^\times$ so it is given by the sign of some real embeddings and some reduction $\bmod I$.

Comment: @Mindlack, Thank you! I got the point of your answer. The key is the local class field theory and Chevotarev density theorem. Thanks!